# Filenames are too long or misformatted?

Tags: sync, files, encoding

I tried to sync from local to Ubuntu One files with filenames such as:

```
176 - Deutsche Geschichte - Ein Versuch Vol 05-Von der Revolution bis zum Drei�igj�hrigen Krieg - 01.mp3  (ungültige Kodierung)"
```

Ubuntu One sync breaks on these filenames and nautilus is shutting down the local file browser window by itself.

Are these Filenames too long for Ubuntu One? Or is it the (ungültige Kodierung) (mis encoded) at the end of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The problem

German umlauts `ä,ö,ü` and `UTF-8` encoding are the problem here. Most likely you copied the files from a windows system (using ISO-8859-1 encoding) to a Linux system (using UTF-8). A computer can only store bits. The mapping of a combination of bits to a real character a human can read is called the encoding. E.g. using UTF-8 the letter `a` is encoded as `01100001`. For umlauts those bit sequences differ in the two encodings, so a UTF-8 system displays another character or doesn't know the bit sequence altogether. That's the whole problem.

#### The solution

With the shell program [convmv](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=convmv) [image: Install convmv] / `sudo apt-get install convmv` you can rename files with broken umlauts to their correct UTF-8 charset. Usage:

```
convmv --notest -r -f ISO8859-1 -t UTF-8 <Verzeichnisname
```

Run that on your files after installing `convmv` by clicking on the Software Center icon above or using the shell command provided next to it. Then try syncing again.

Good luck on sharing German history! :D

Comment: Ok, youre right. The encodings were the problem not the filename size. Converted to utf-8 the upload works well. I think we need some error messages for ubuntu one. Sadly, i´ve probably choosen the wrong sourceencoding for convmv, so the umlaute are still not readable. But its detected as utf-8 so everything works well.

Comment: Excellent answer con-f-use !

Comment: Thanks at @Rinzwind. At MattscheAN Windows is known to use either ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15 or Windows-1252 for European versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also revert the conversion by calling `convmv` the other way round. Then you can look for the correct `charset`, try **cp850**.